# On exponential polynomials

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we have the following function $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$
$$f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^k P_i(t)\exp(\alpha_i t),$$
where $\alpha_i$s are all algebraic numbers and $P_i(t)$ are all polynomials with algebraic coefficients and degree less than $m$.

There are several questions that I am interested in.

a. What is the maximal number $p$ such that there is a $t_0$ and for all $r\leq p$
$$f^{(r)}(t_0)=0.$$
b. Suppose $t_1,\cdots,t_q,\cdots$ are the real roots of $f(t)=0$, is it possible to have a converging sequence of $t_q$? In other words, is it possible to have Cauchy sequence $t_i$ such that $f(t_i)=0$? If not, do we have a lower bound of the distance between different roots?

c.Is there an algorithm to decide whether there is some common real root of $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$?

Comment: As to (a) a trivial general remark is that $f$ solves a linear homogeneous ODE (with constant coefficients) of order $\sum_{i=1}^k\big(1+\text{deg}P_i\big)\le km$, so certainly $p<km$ otherwise $f$ is identically zero by uniqueness of the Cauchy problem.

Comment: @Pietro Majer Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

a) I'm not sure in general, but if $k=2$ a function of the form $A(t) \exp(t) + A(-t) \exp(-t)$ 
where $A$ is a polynomial of degree $m-1$ can give you $p=m+1$ if $m$ is odd, or $m+2$ if $m$ is even, with $t_0 = 0$.

b) The function $f$ is entire, so (except in the trivial case where it is identically $0$) its roots are a discrete set, and there can't be any such Cauchy sequences.

c) What do you mean by "compute"?  In most cases, I would expect the roots in question (if there are any) to be transcendental numbers not expressible in "closed form".  For example, this would be the case for 
$ f(x) = (t + \cos(t))^2$.  On the other hand, standard numerical methods can be used to get arbitrarily good approximations of roots.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the last question into deciding the existance of common root. What is the reason of the roots distribution of entire function?